# Redux dispatch never run in React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an authentication action on an react native app which must during the authentication go to perform another action but it is never executed (`dispatch(getMobiles())`). I do not understand why. Do you have an idea ?

If my authentication went well, I immediately want to retrieve data on my new users, so I want to execute getMobiles () which is another action.

thanks in advance :)

**auth actions**

```
export const authentication = (
  username: String,
  password: String,
  label: String,
  synchro: Boolean,
  url: String,
) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: LOGIN.PENDING, payload: ''});

    const type = UDA_URL_LIST.map(uda => {
      if (uda.url === url) {
        return uda.name;
      }
    })
      .join()
      .replace(/[, ]+/g, ' ')
      .trim();

    fetchUser(url, username.trim(), password.trim())
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.err) {
          const newUser = {
            ...response,
            label,
            type,
            synchro,
          };
          dispatch({type: LOGIN.SUCCESS, payload: newUser});

          // not dispatched !
          return dispatch(getMobiles(url, response.key, newUser.userId));
        }
      })
      .catch(err => dispatch({type: LOGIN.ERROR, payload: err}));
  };
};
```

**getMobiles**

```
export const getMobiles = (
  url: String | null = null,
  token: String,
  userId: String,
) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: MOBILES.PENDING, payload: ''});
    fetchMobiles(url, token)
      .then(mobilesList => {
        dispatch({
          type: MOBILES.SUCCESS,
          payload: mobilesList.data,
          meta: {userId},
        });
      })
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in getMobiles require second call with parametr dispatch,
try to use `getMobiles(url, response.key, newUser.userId)(dispatch)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it doesn't work for me